# Find out Python interpreter memory consumption

Tags: python, tracemalloc

How can I find out Python interpreter memory consumption?

I tried [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) but it shows running code memory consumption.

PS. It seems tracemalloc does what I want

Comment: "It seems tracemalloc does what I want" – then why don't you use it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I mean I just started diving into memory management and optimization in Python